# Setting up a JavaScript variable from Spring model by using Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf as template engine. How I pass a variable from Spring model to JavaScript variable?

Spring-side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String messages(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "hello");
    return "index";
}
```

Client-side:

```
<script>
    ....
    var m = ${message}; // not working
    alert(m);
    ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 266, accepted):

According to the official **[documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)**:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var message = /*[[${message}]]*/ 'default';
    console.log(message);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work... javascript error uncaught syntax error

Comment: Works fine, also possible to read from messages.properties: var msg = [[#{msg}]];

Comment: @szxnyc if you forget the `/*<![CDATA[*/` macro you will get that.

Comment: Also take attention to `<script th:inline="javascript">`

Comment: How to make it work when using external script via`th:src="@{/js/script.js}"` ?

Comment: @MichałStochmal you can load inline javascript on top of external javascript and use same variables(defined in inline javascript) in external javascript.

Comment: this works for me     
// <![CDATA[
      var abc = 'somepath?someParam=[[${fromController}]]' ;
     // ]]>

Comment: The CDATA is not needed if you use Thymeleaf 3

Answer (score 32):

Thymeleaf 3 now:

- Display a constant:

  ```
  <script th:inline="javascript">
  var MY_URL = /*[[${T(com.xyz.constants.Fruits).cheery}]]*/ "";
  </script>
  ```
- Display a variable:

  ```
  var message = [[${message}]];
  ```
- Or in a comment to have a valid JavaScript code when you open your template file in a static manner (without executing it at a server).

  Thymeleaf calls this: JavaScript natural templates

  ```
  var message = /*[[${message}]]*/ "";
  ```

  Thymeleaf will ignore everything we have written after the comment and before the semicolon.

More info: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining

Comment: thanks you! wanna gave you a beer i was looking for this syntax   var MY_URL = /*[[${T(com.xyz.constants.Fruits).cheery}]]*/ "";

Answer (score 23):

```
var message =/*[[${message}]]*/ 'defaultanyvalue';
```

Comment: Notice it should be NO space between /* */ and the contained [[ ]].

Comment: It's worth noting that the `defaultanyvalue` will only be used when running the page statically, i.e. outside a web container. If ran inside a container and the variable `message` hasn't been declared the resulting source code will be `var message = null;`

Comment: Also important to add `th:inline="javascript"` to the script tag.

Answer (score 15):

MAKE sure you have thymleaf on page already

```
//Use this in java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/showingTymleafTextInJavaScript")
public String thankYou(Model model){
 model.addAttribute("showTextFromJavaController","dummy text");
 return "showingTymleafTextInJavaScript";
}


//thymleaf page  javascript page
<script>
var showtext = "[[${showTextFromJavaController}]]";
console.log(showtext);
</script>
```

Answer (score 14):

According [to the documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining) there are several ways to do the inlining.
The right way you must choose based on the situation.

1) Simply put the variable from server to javascript :

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

var message = [[${message}]];
alert(message);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

2) Combine javascript variables with server side variables, e.g. you need to create link for requesting inside the javascript:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        function sampleGetByJquery(v) {
            /*[+
            var url = [[@{/my/get/url(var1=${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('var1')})}]] 
                      + "&var2="+v;
             +]*/
            $("#myPanel").load(url, function() {});
        }
        /*]]>*/
        </script>
```

**The one situation I can't resolve** - then I need to pass javascript variable inside the Java method calling inside the template (it's impossible I guess).

Answer (score 9):

If you use Thymeleaf 3:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var username = [[${session.user.name}]];
</script>
```

Comment: This should get more votes, now that Thymeleaf 3 is pretty much the norm, yes? The manual link should also be updated. https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#text-inlining ...I just shipped a float[] with audio data to a web page for the first time. Can play it with Web Audio API! This question and these answer were a big help in locating the Javascript inlining used.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen this kind of thing work in the wild:

```
<input type="button"  th:onclick="'javascript:getContactId(\'' + ${contact.id} + '\');'" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming request attribute named "message":

```
request.setAttribute("message", "this is my message");
```

To read it in the html page using Thymeleaf template:

```
<script>
  var message = "[[${message}]]";
  alert(message);
</script>
```

Comment: Have XSS vulnerability!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to display your variable unescaped, use this format:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var message = /*[(${message})]*/ 'default';

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Note the `[(` brackets which wrap the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to create a dynamic javascript returned by a java controller like it is written here in the thymeleaf forum: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Can-I-use-th-inline-for-a-separate-javascript-file-td4025766.html

> One way to handle this is to create a dynamic javascript file with the
> URLs embedded in it. Here are the steps (if you are using Spring MVC)

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"/dynamic.js"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/javascript")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String dynamicJS(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return "Your javascript code....";

}
```