# Pass a variable from thymeleaf to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I have an html file, thymeleaf, that has a variable passed from the controller that I need to give to a function on an external javascript file.
How do I do this ?

I can get the variable like

```
<label th:utext="${id}" ></label>
```

I need to pass that id to a function that's inside

```
<script th:src="@{/js/myfunctions.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

There's a function there :

```
function myFunction(id){

}
```

Comment: do as th:onclick="myfunction('[[(${id})]]')"

Comment: seems to be already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25688291/6157415

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="yourId" th:value="${id}"/>
```

Then in your js function :

```
function myFunction(){
 var val = $("#yourId").val();
}
```

Note that I use Jquery but the principe is the same.

If the JS function code is in your html page (not .js external file) you can access the model value like this :

```
function myFunction(){
  var val = "${id}";
}
```

Comment: I cannot do like this `var val = "${id}";`

Comment: how can assing to an external file without assign in the html a big json?

Answer (score 4):

Inline HTML example:

`th:onclick="${'myFunction(' + id + ');'}"`

Comment: I have an use case where id needs to be resolved like  '1234'  (with the single quotes) any idea how that can be done.

Comment: @p.k  `<span th:attr="onclick=${'doThis('+ '''' + user.getTestJquery() + '''' + ')'}">aaaa</span>` should do it When I inspect element I see: `<span onclick="doThis('presetValue')">aaaa</span>`

Answer (score 4):

try this:
(a bit late to the party)

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

th:attr="onChange=|yourFunction(${id})|" </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass a variable like that:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">myFunction(/*[[${id}]]*/);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
//for parameter
function myfunction ([[${id}]]){
    //this is for address rout 
    window.location=[[@{/user}]]
}
```

use `[[]]` and put thymleaf expression