# javascript variable in location.href

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

In javascript I have this variable:

```
var selectedItemId = null; // the actual value is set from another function
```

Then I have this function:

```
function editLink() {
    location.href = /*[[@{/supplycontracts/edit/}]]*/'';
}
```

Now I want to add the variable to the href, so that in the end it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/supplycontracts/edit/?contractId=4
```

The number '4' at the end is the already substituted selectedItemId.

I tried stuff like this:

```
location.href = /*[[@{/supplycontracts/edit(${selectedItemId})}]]*/'';
```

But it didnt work.

If I do this:

```
location.href = /*[[@{/supplycontracts/edit(selectedItemId)}]]*/'';
```

I only get

```
http://localhost:8080/supply-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/supplycontracts/edit?selectedItemId
```

How do I have to pass the selectedItemId to the href so I get the correct link?

Comment: '';  look strange ! Is it some pragma code?

Comment: No, it's a thymeleaf featuer I think. The very first code I showed actually works. It sends me to the generic edit page. However I need the parameter so I can edit a specific item.

Comment: It is all embedded in this:
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" class="init">

/*<![CDATA[*/
.....
/*]]>*/

</script>

Comment: Spring from Java i guest. Is it possible to make it simple like :   location.href = /*[[@{/supplycontracts/edit/}]]*/'' + selectedItemId; , take look this qnswer maybe can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687816/setting-up-a-javascript-variable-from-spring-model-by-using-thymeleaf

Comment: You're right, I use Java, Spring and Thymeleaf. I am trying the stuff from the answer you linked. Your suggestion does not seem to work because the strings at the don't make it into the final link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, adding the parameter in the same line, as suggested by Nikola Lukic, did not work for me, although I have seen this notation in other sources as well. What finally worked is this:

```
function editLink() {
    var baseUrl = /*[[@{/supplycontracts/edit}]]*/'';
    location.href = baseUrl + "?contractId=" + selectedItemId;
}
```