# How to handle variable from Spring controller using javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Guys i have problem to get data from variable after execute rest in my controller. Here is sample to show my problem.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/editSchema/{id}")
public String editSchemaById(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Integer id)
{
    model.addAttribute("message", "why this isn't working...");
    return "redirect:/drawdiagram";
}
```

**JavaScript** *drawdiagram.html*

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var message = /*[[${message}]]*/ 'default';
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

**Result**

[image]

**Anyony can tell me why i have null there?**
I really don't know what is going on :(
Maybe this is bad way? I have chosen thymeleaf but maybe there is some other way?

**All i need to do is:**
1. Click button.
2. Execute some backend code and get data to variable in controller.
3. Redirect to other page.
4. Execute some JavaScript code which is based on that variable.

.

***Sources:***

1. https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart
2. [Setting up a JavaScript variable from Spring model by using Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687816/setting-up-a-javascript-variable-from-spring-model-by-using-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are redirecting to another controller `drawdiagram`, the values in model object won't be available in other controller. So here you need to set the value first using either `RedirectAttributes#addFlashAttribute` or `RedirectAttributes#addAttribute`, and then get the value in the other controller -using `@ModelAttribute("message")`.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/editSchema/{id}")
public String editSchemaById(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Integer id, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "why this isn't working...");
    return "redirect:/drawdiagram";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "drawdiagram", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String OtherController(@ModelAttribute("message") String message, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", message);
    return "drawdiagram";
}
```