# How to get variable as response FROM controller TO JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have the following code:

```
@RestController
public class RestTmp {

    @Autowired
    SchemasService schemasService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/editSchema/{id}")
    public void editSchemaById(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Integer id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String schemaERD = schemasService.editUser(id);
        model.addAttribute("message", schemaERD);
        response.sendRedirect("/drawdiagram");
    }
}
```

**Can anyone tell me how i can get value from that variable "message" now?**
I need to handle that value in my *"/drawdiagram" ---> (drawdiagram.html)*

I tried with thymeleaf something like that:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var message = /*[[${message}]]*/ 'default';
    console.log(message);

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

but i am getting null all the time ... Can someone help me? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are adding the "comment-statement" (/* and */) once too many times. Remove them in the inner part. And keep the square brackets.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var message = [[${message}]];   <--- Keep square brackets on this line.
    console.log(message);

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I used the same link user404 mentions in the comment-section in that persons answer and that is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

inside your script tag, try this:

```
 var message = '${message}';
```

Comment: Thanks man but this is not solution for me :(  https://i.imgur.com/TbZWPNs.png  I don't know why but this is just normal "string" for compiler.

Comment: may be, this one can help: [Setting up a JavaScript variable from Spring model by using Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687816/setting-up-a-javascript-variable-from-spring-model-by-using-thymeleaf)

Comment: I tried that also and i am getting null :( I mentioned that in my post.

Comment: check if your `message` variable really sets null in controller.

Comment: Variable "message" in controller is ok, i tried also put sample string like "whatever string" into that "message" and i am getting null also. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBMw8.png