# How to pass a java ArrayList of Strings to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I have an javaScript function in my Thymeleaf page which has an array of countries

```
  var countries = ["Australia","Italy","France","Spain","India","China"];
```

But I want to pass that list of Countries from the controller method. So I passed an List of strings to the view via the model and accessed it in javaScript as follows,

Controller:

```
 List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Australia");
    list.add("Italy");
    list.add("France");
    list.add("Spain");
    list.add("India");
    list.add("China");

    model.addAttribute("list",list);
```

javaScript:

```
 var countries=[[${list}]];
```

But It doesn't work as expected.So please suggest a way to do this successfully

Comment: Shouldn't that be just normal array? var countries = list; incase if you are getting that from an API call it should be var countries = response.data

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25688291/11285149

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up a JavaScript variable from Spring model by using Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687816/setting-up-a-javascript-variable-from-spring-model-by-using-thymeleaf)